# styling of react-owlcarousel.. how do i override the generated classes with mine

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have read the documentation but I dont know how to implement the owlcarousel classess and the options in there. So that I can style the inline classes like Owl-stage, Owl-item etc to mine wants of styling..

Have tried adding the owlcarousel classes and the options too.

```
import React from 'react';
import OwlCarousel from 'react-owl-carousel';
import "owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css";
import "owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.css";
import  "../css/Owlcarousel.css";

class Owlcarousel extends React.Component{


    render(){
        const options = ({
            nav: !0,
            items: 1,
            stageElement:'div',
            center: 1,
            navText: ['<i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i>', '<i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>'],
            responsive: {
                1700: {
                    stagePadding: 620,
                    margin:120
                },
                1430: {
                    stagePadding: 320,
                    margin:100
                },
                1025: {
                    stagePadding:280,
                    margin:10
                },
                768: {
                    stagePadding: 150,
                    margin:50
                },
                0: {
                    stagePadding: 0,
                    margin: 0
                }
            }
        })

        return(
            <section>
            <div className="container">


                    <OwlCarousel 
                    loop
                    margin={10}
                    nav
                    items={1}
                    dots={false}
                    options={options}
                    ref="gallery"
                    id="testimonials-2"
                    className="owl-theme"
                    stageClass= 'stageName'
                    itemElement = {"section"}

                    >
```

I want to be able to override the generated  classes and inline styling...